# In Talend API tester, how to send a request without evaluating environment variables in ${}

Tags: templates, environment, talend

I have a request I want to send using Talend API tester.

In the request there are instances where I want to send a payload such as:

```
{ "channel" : "${channelId}" }.
```

But Talend API tester evaluates anything in a `${}` as an environment variable, thus they payload sent will be in the form:

```
{ "channel" : "channelId" }.
```

Is there any way to force the API tester to ignore the `${}` delimiter, and send it with the payload so that it may be evaluated internally once it has reached the server.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused by using "Talend API Tester" as my API Client software.

This API tester allows for Environment Variables to be set which will be evaluated before the payload is sent.

Since I had no environment variable set to "channelId" the content: ${channelId} was being evaluated to just "channelId".

To solve the issue I have found two solutions:

1. Use a different API Client such as Postman API Client.
2. Set Talend API Tester to not evaluate Environment Variables by unchecking the [Enable Body Evaluation] button just below the Body section in the Talend API Tester. ( I had looked into the main Settings, but never found any solution. It wasn't in the Settings, but on the middle of the main Client)